# Can Google Chrome or Firefox be embedded in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, google-chrome, firefox, chromium-embedded

Is there a way to embed Chrome or Firefox in WPF? In other words, can a user control be created with either? If some already exist, which would you recommend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can embed Chrome (Chromium) in a WPF application.

You can use :

- [The Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) (Same one used in Github for Windows. can be used with any .Net language)
- [Awesomium](https://awesomium.com/) (free for non commercial apps and Indie devs ([making less than $100k/year](https://awesomium.com/buy/)))

Comment: Cool thanks for that I'm trying the first one first as it's open-source (+1).